# Are there any Final Fantasy Spirits in Super Smash Bros Ultimate?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

At some point the game informed me that you get a small boost by matching your character with spirits of the same game series.

I mostly play as Cloud but have never obtained a single Final Fantasy spirit.

Are there any in the game?

Comment: I have not found any resources validating that first claim.  You should be able to perform very well without worrying about whether or not the source game of the spirit matches the source game of your fighters.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann It came up as a message box or something similar when playing spirit mode. I have completed spirit mode on hard just thought it might be handy for collecting the spirits in the other mode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## No.

Cloud (the Fighter Spirit) is the only Final Fantasy Spirit in Ultimate.

From [the Wiki page](https://www.ssbwiki.com/List_of_spirits_(Final_Fantasy_series)):

> *Final Fantasy* is the only series represented only by its respective playable character, without any additional type of Spirit depicting them.

and

> *Final Fantasy* is the only series represented by a fighter not to have any Spirits besides Fighter Spirits.

And also:

> Before the final release of the game, many believed that the Final Fantasy series had no Spirits at all, due to the many speculative resources having no Spirits listed for the Final Fantasy franchise, Midgar once again having only two music tracks, Cloud being solely voiced in Japanese, and a rumor that stated Cloud was absent from World of Light. All of these circumstances lead to many fans complaining about Square Enix not letting Nintendo properly use their license, however, it is most likely because of conflicting copyrights and contracts Square had in place before their inclusion in Ultimate's development, as is the case with Cloud not speaking in English.

So it sounds like due to the usual Square Enix copyright situation surrounding Final Fantasy and Cloud in Smash, Sakurai's team was unable to get any FF spirits outside of Fighter Cloud.